# What is the correct format to save live tweets with tweepy, continue to append to json?

Tags: python, json, serialization, twitter, tweepy

I am working on retrieving live tweets for a specific time period with tweepy. Currently, my on_data method looks like this:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        tweet_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet_data['Curr_time'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print(tweet_data["text"])
        with open(self.file_store_tweets, 'a') as f:
            f.write('\n')
            f.write(json.dumps(tweet_data))
```

I don't need everything in the tweet, but want to save it as fast as possible so that I don't stop my program from continuing to get the latest live tweets. 
I would like to save the user's handle/profile info I.e. # followers, # following etc., definitely the tweet text itself obviously, the # likes or retweets, the location (when applicable), the time tweeted, and then I add the time I retrieved it.

Any suggestions for people familiar with tweepy, or is this the best way to do it and then read it in as dictionaries?

Comment: This is open-ended. Saving as json doesn't sound practical, get a database

Comment: @roganjosh do you know how to save tweets from tweepy directly to big query db, or would I have to save it to a json and then load